# Unit tests for java backend app using jaxrs, dao with jpql, running on glassfish

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-rs, jpql, dao

I am thinking about writing JUnits to my CRUD app, but I am wandering is there really a point of having real unit tests. I will show you my basic app structure. In general client app calls REST end point to get list of workers (pagination info included) using service and then dao for accessing database (jpql language). Here is basic structure of it:

```
class WorkerRequest {

  private int pageSize;
  private int pageNumber;

}

class WorkerController{

  @POST
  public Response getWorkers(final WorkerRequest request) {
    return Response.ok(workerService.getWorkers(request)).build();
  }

}

class WorkerService{

  public WorkerResponseDTO getWorkers(final WorkerRequest request) {
    final long totalWorkerCount = workerDao.getTotalCount(request);
    final List<WorkerDTO> workers =     
    workerDao.getWorkers(request).stream().map(WorkerDTO::new).collect(toList());
    return new WorkerResponseDTO(totalWorkerCount, workers);
  }

}


class WorkerDao implements BasicWorkerDao{

  @Override
  public List<Worker> getWorkersForPage(final WorkerRequest request) {
    final String query = "select w from Worker w";
    return entityManager.createQuery(query, Worker.class)
        .setFirstResult(util.calcStartPosition(request))
        .setMaxResults(request.getPageSize())
        .getResultList();
  }

  @Override
  public long getTotalWorkerCount(final WorkerRequest request) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select count(w) from Worker w", Long.class).getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

Now I am thinking, it there really a point for me to introduce real unit tests? I mean I can mock my real dao with some MockDao and in there I can simply introduce arraylist of workers. But how this would work?

For example in real scenario if I pass a request with pageSize=20, and pageNumber=4 I want workers from 61 to 80, that means I will simply write in my MockDao in getWorkersForPage code like list.stream().skip((pageNumber-1)*pageSize).limit(pageSize), and that is all? It seems silly for me.

Maybe if dao was responsible for getting all workers always, and service would then, filter it, did some sorting, calculate pagination etc than it would make sense to have those unit tests. But when SQL is doing all the job is it wort it to use this MockDao ?

Or maybe the only way to test this feature/app is to provide a integration tests with some memory db, and then test would make sense, since I would test sql statements as well.

I hope you know what I mean, what is usually your approach, what is the best approach in this case?

cheers

Comment: This is extremely opinion-driven question, so I'm going to vote to close it. My opinion, though, is this: unit tests are valuable, and you do need them. In your particular case, though, mock is indeed silly, because Dao does most of the work - but what about having unit tests of your particular dao implementation, where you inspect what query it emits to underlying database? As for service tests - your service does more than just paginate results, and it'd be worth to inspect what DTO it emits in response to particular requests. Also, I'm pretty sure tests of `Util.calc...` are important too.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thank you for your opinion. I never said that unit test are not valuable, I was just questioning their existence in this kind of application. I somehow did not think that I could test how SQL is generated based on my request. That is great idea! especially that I have already included filtering and sorting. Also test for page calculation as well. But when you are talking about testing service - response base on given input, you meant with the use of some MockDao, right ? thanks again for your input

Comment: Yes, for service test you'll pretty much need a MockDao over some well-known `List<Worker>`, and verify that service returns correct DTO with proper total and sublist of workers.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thank you for your suggestions, I really appreciate